# Common Mode Input Capacitance

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, photodiode

[image]

If I were to follow the same circuit diagram as provided in the image above, must I include Ccm myself? Or is this capacitance value apart of the op amp itself?

Wondering the same for diode capacitance, that is the capacitance value associated with the photodiode sensor itself and not an external capacitor correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ccm is just a circuit model capacitance, the sum of all capacitances affecting the input node. It includes e.g. op-amp capacitance and PCB wiring capacitance that are present in the circuit so it is not a capacitor the user provides.

Cd is model for photodiode junction capacitance. It also is not a capacitor that the user provides.